# How to avoid multi-level ternary operators with .editorconfig

Tags: c#, editorconfig

I have this C# method:

```
public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(BaseGetAllRequest) || context.Metadata.ModelType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseGetAllRequest)))
    {
        return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(SearchFiltersBinder));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Which when I run Visual Studio Code Cleanup, becomes this:

```
public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context) => context == null
        ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context))
        : context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(BaseGetAllRequest) || context.Metadata.ModelType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseGetAllRequest))
        ? new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(SearchFiltersBinder))
        : (IModelBinder)null;
```

I have enabled using [expression bodied methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods), where possible, so it makes sense. But in this case, it actually makes the code less readable (in my opinion at least). Is there a way where I can limit the `.editorconfig` to a maximum depth (i.e. max one questionmark) for expression bodied methods?

Comment: Any luck so far?

Comment: I still have not found a solution to this, no. I will update my post, should I find one.